# Mean, variance, .., higher variances?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, random-variables, entropy

#### TL; DR

Let $e,v$ be two real numbers.

- The constant distribution $f \equiv e$ is **universal** in the sense that it has the most *entropy* among those that have mean being $e$. We define *variance* using this fact.
- The normal distribution $N(e,v)$ is **universal** in the sense that it has the most *entropy* among those that have mean being $e$ and variance being $v$. We define *2-variance* using this fact.
- What's next? What's the name of the study along this vein?

#### Original post

The study of a random variable $X$ is the study of its underlying distribution $P_X$. However, it's too expensive, so we wish to start simple. To make life even simpler, let's assume all variables are from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The simplest yet important information of $X$ is its mean $E(X)$. Once we know its mean, we can ask further questions.. like how much does $X$ differ from the **universal** distribution among those with mean $E(X)$? Here by **universal**, I mean the distribution(s) possessing the maximal **entropy** among those that have the same mean. Of course, it's the constant distribution $f \equiv E(X)$, taking value at $E(X)$.

Moving forward, we wish to see how much $X$ differs from $E(X)$. We of course take their difference $|X - E(X)|$, but decide to consider instead of its square $(X-E(X))^2$.. because why not? It's both easier to analyze and yet equivalent to the difference. Same as when we thought $X$ contains too much information, so does $(X-E(X))^2$. Hence, we again consider its mean $E((X-E(X))^2)$, and coin it to be $Var(X)$.

We wish to move forward, and derive higher versions of variances. **I'm aware of usual higher moments $E((X - E(X))^n)$ but that's not what I want.** What I want is to keep following the same vein of thought, and consider the difference of $X$ with the universal distribution that has the known attributes.

Henceforth, we consider the difference $|X - N(E(X),Var(X))|$, where $N$ denotes the normal distribution, because the normal distribution is the one that has the most **entropy** among those that have mean $E(X)$ and variance $Var(X)$. Let's again consider the square with the same reason as above. And so we define the $2$-variance

$$Var_2(X) := E ( (X-N(E(X),Var(X))^2 ),$$

and so on.

#### Questions

1. What is the **universal** distribution with mean $E(X)$, variance $Var(X)$, and 2-variance $Var_2(X)$? Again by universal I mean the one that has the most **entropy** among those having the same known attributes.
2. What's the standard name for $Var_2, Var_3, \cdots$?

Comment: I am not sure your notion of 2-variance really makes sense in the same way as it does with the ordinary variance, because with a constant distribution there is no distinction going on between numbers and random variables and thus no joint distribution to reconcile. How do you define the joint distribution of $X$ and $N(E(X),\mathrm{Var}(X))$? It cannot be independent, because then a normal distribution wouldn't have 2-variance zero.

Comment: Maybe the right notion of 2-variance is the 2-Wasserstein distance between a distribution and the corresponding $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution?

Comment: @lan I'm learning statistics by myself so maybe I've missed something important.. please point out where I've been naive.. In my case I wish to make things simple.. so I visualize $X$ as a smooth function $f$ that integrates to $1$. In this case, $E(X)$ is just $\int xf(x)\,dx$. I visualize $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ as the corresponding Gaussian function $G$. So by $E( |X - N(\mu, \sigma^2) |^2)$ I really mean $\int x (f(x) - G(x))^2 \,dx$.

Comment: But that is not how you got the variance; it was not $\int x(f(x)-\delta_\mu(x))^2 dx$, which is actually not even a well-defined thing. It was instead $\int (x-\mu)^2 f(x) dx$. Without a joint distribution there is no way to do the subtraction like this when the other variable isn't degenerate: what you need is $\int \int (x-y)^2 f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$, but that depends on the joint distribution whereas what you want to do should only depend on the marginals.

Comment: Maybe I misused some term.. why can't I take $\int x |f(x) - g(x)|^2 \,dx$ where $g(x)$ is $exp(\frac{1}{2}((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2)/\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: There is no $g$ such that the variance is of that form, so doing what you said is not analogous to the variance. Actually, doing what you said is likely quite degenerate because there is no guarantee that it's even positive.

Comment: @Ian I see what you mean. I was trying to understand the "difference" of two distributions.. I will learn from what you posted and rethink my question. Thank you!